# Add XML file to the file list

Tags: xml, doxygen

I want to add the contents of an XML file to doxygen generated documentation. I added the XML file to the `INPUT` tag of the doxygen configuration file. However, while the XML file is listed in the file list, the contents of the file are not shown. What do I have to do to include the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen does not have native support for parsing XML, so you cannot use `INPUT`, but you can include the contents of an XML file in the output.

Suppose your XML file is called `test.xml` and is located in directory `xml` (relative to where doxygen is run). Then you can use the following comment block:

```
/** @page xml_example My XML File
 *  Here is my xml file included in the doxygen output:
 *  @verbinclude test.xml
 */
```

to make sure doxygen can find the XML file you need to set the path to the xml directory

```
EXAMPLE_PATH = xml
```

Comment: Thanks ;) Do you know if it is also possible to create a new custom tab like "examples" or "related pages"?

Comment: If you get the latest snapshot from SVN you can create a custom layout file (with the -l option) and there you can add user defined tabs. Build the documentation from SVN by running make in the doc dir for details on how to define such user defined tabs.