# How to embed/convert XML document for Doxygen documentation?

Tags: xml, doxygen

I have a question!

I already have some code, which is being auto-documented by Doxygen. In addition, I want to add a rather long `mainpage` to this documentation. The page I want to include is in XML, like [this page](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml), for example. I know Doxygen supports only a handful of popular tags and not the rest. So how can I embed an xml page into my documentation's mainpage, or convert it to a dox file that uses doxygen special commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`\htmlinclude`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhtmlinclude) command. To incorporate the page you link to in your question I saved the source of the page as `dox.xml`, placed it in the same directory as a minimal test source file and included the following in the source file:

```
/**
  \mainpage
  \htmlinclude dox.xml
*/
```

I also had to add the current directory to the `EXAMPLE_PATH` field of the configuration file since this is where `\htmlinclude` (and [`\verbinclude`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude), another useful command) searches for files to include.

There are a number of useful related questions and answers on this site, including:

[Add XML file to the file list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986095/add-xml-file-to-the-file-list/8992867#8992867)

[Is there a way to embed <script> content into a Doxygen \mainpage section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315493/is-there-a-way-to-embed-script-content-into-a-doxygen-mainpage-section/7324488#7324488)

[How to include custom files in Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052036/how-to-include-custom-files-in-doxygen)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I later realized that if I took that approach, and generated LaTeX or PDF out of Doxygen, things would not show up properly, so I had to make a parser that would convert xml tags to doxygen special commands. But if I generate HTML only, then this method still works, with some colour coding missing, e.g., in `<code>` tags.